# Depth Sense Camera to PointCloud2 in RVIZ?

Tags: rviz, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,
I am currently running on ROS Kinetic on Ubuntu and would like to know how am i supposed to display the raw data captured from my Soft Kinetic DS 325 camera to a pointcloud on rviz? Currently I am not able to view any topics when i open rviz. Help would be very much appreciated. Thank you!

Currently i have 4 terminals running (Images are attached below):
1)roscore
2) the depthsense viewer software downloaded from their website
3) the terminal in which i am trying to run a launch file i cloned off github , with the error
4) rviz ( the screenshot with what i view in rviz is also attached below)

[C:\fakepath\Screenshot from 2017-09-28 01_08_15.png](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/15065001896805145.png)

[C:\fakepath\Screenshot from 2017-09-28 01_13_49.png](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/1506500204227539.png)

[C:\fakepath\Screenshot from 2017-09-28 01_06_47.png](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/15065002372962505.png)

[C:\fakepath\Screenshot from 2017-09-28 01_07_20.png](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/1506500252753551.png)

Rviz & RQT screenshots (updated):
[C:\fakepath\Screenshot from 2017-09-28 22_59_53.png](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/15065789268819547.png)

[C:\fakepath\Screenshot from 2017-09-28 23_00_06.png](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/1506578943341265.png)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/271573/depth-sense-camera-to-pointcloud2-in-rviz?/) by [herroineedhelp](https://answers.ros.org/users/32024/herroineedhelp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2017-09-26

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-09-26**:
Are you running the node that runs the Kinect?

**Comment by [herroineedhelp](https://answers.ros.org/users/32024/herroineedhelp/) on 2017-09-26**:
Hi, I'm not using a Kinect but a depth sense camera so I believe the node is known as " softkinetic_camera" . I've tried running it but it just gives me an error of not being able to launch type of node.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-09-26**:
Please update your question with a copy and paste of how you are running it and the error.

**Comment by [herroineedhelp](https://answers.ros.org/users/32024/herroineedhelp/) on 2017-09-27**:
Hi, i wanted to upload a screenshot of how i am running it but apparently i am not able to do so as i have less than (5 points?). So I have just updated the question with the terminals that i am running with. Should you require any screenshots that could be of help i could email you !

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2017-09-27**:
I have up voted to give you karma Now you can post more info.

**Comment by [herroineedhelp](https://answers.ros.org/users/32024/herroineedhelp/) on 2017-09-27**:
Hi all i have updated the questions with the supported screen shots. Thank you for helping

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2017-09-27**:
from the rviz screenshot, i could say that you have to add pointcloud topic to view it,  can you share "`rqt_graph`" screenshot.

**Comment by [herroineedhelp](https://answers.ros.org/users/32024/herroineedhelp/) on 2017-09-28**:
hello! i have updated with the screenshots from both rviz and the rqt graph. currently, what i am trying to achieve is for my camera to view the yellow tape as a point cloud in rviz. and i would like to ask, how to link the base camera link with my map in rviz?

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2017-09-28**:
choose the camera frame in rviz by selecting "Global Options-->Fixed Frame-->"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

HI all i've answered my own question by making several adjustments to the codes. Thank you.

---

Originally posted by [herroineedhelp](https://answers.ros.org/users/32024/herroineedhelp/) with karma: 36 on 2017-10-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: -1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-10-03**:
What adjustments did you make? Can you please include them? Otherwise, this isn't an answer.